# Applying render transform from data template at runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a silverlight application in which I have a data template as follows

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="Template">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding txtCap}"/>
    <Grid>
       <Grid.RenderTransform>
           <CompositeTransform/>
           <TranslateTransform x:Name="gridTransform" X="0" Y="0"/>
       </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding txtContent}"/>
    <Grid>
<StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `data template` is the the template for an `items control`, and the items control itself is bound to an `ObservableCollection`

Inside the code, I am actually able to get any of the grids that I am dragging (for eg: `sender as Grid` in mouse down event) but I want to ask about how do I actually apply the transform when I have this control?
For eg: I have this in a mouse event: `var targetLB = sender as ContentControl;`
but how do I apply translate transform to this element at runtime?

If this wouldn't have been in a data template, I would have directly accesses the name of the TranslateTransform and done something like `this.gridTransform.X = ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the properties of the Transform as well.

EDIT:

> Inside the code, I am actually able to get any of the grids that I am dragging (for eg: sender as Grid in mouse down event)

If you have the grid, you can get the TranslateTransform object like this:

```
        var transform = ((sender as Grid).RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[1] as TranslateTransform;
        transform.X = ...
        transform.Y = ...
```

Comment: I only want to `TranslateTransform` the Grid that I am currently dragging I don't understand how to apply TranslateTransform in runtime